# Scientific notation with E

Tags: java

I am trying to represent the number `.0002` as `2.0 x 10 ^ -4`. 
Here is what I have so far

```
public static String toScientificNotation(double n) {
    int exponent = 0;
    if( n < 1){
        String doubleValue = Double.toString(Math.abs(n));
        int format = doubleValue.indexOf(".");
        int decimalPlacesToMove = (doubleValue.length() - (format - 1));
    }
```

No matter what I try i get `E` in the output. If someone can give me a pseudo code. It would be a great help. I cannot use `BigDecimal` or anything other than `double`.

Comment: How many digits after the decimal do you plan on inputting?

Comment: The maximum can be 6

Comment: I think you mean `2.0 x 10 ^ -4`

Comment: Yes, sorry about that

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html

Comment: What shall happen to values like 1.0, -32.0002 and others?

Comment: @SebastianHöffner they will just be represented with exponent of 0 (Eg 1.0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I reworked your method into the following; you can use it as a basis/skeleton to convert the double into the scientific notation you want, avoiding the `E` altogether. You can expand on it by creating implementations for `n > 1` and `n < 0`

```
private static String toScienticNotation(double n) {

    String result = "";

    if (n < 1 && n > 0) {

        int counter = 0;
        double answer = n;

        while (answer < 1) {
            answer = answer * 10;
            counter--;
        }

        result = String.valueOf(answer) + " x 10 ^ "
                + String.valueOf(counter);
    }
    return result;
}
```

It works by multiplying the input `n` by 10, `counter` number of times, until `n` is greater than 1. This is a substitute formula to manually discover the number of decimal points rather than using the String methods.

Comment: Thank you. I did the math by hand and had done the code. But thank you still.

Answer (score 1):

The method you were using would work fine, but there's an easier way using formatter:

```
    import java.util.*;
    import java.text.*;
    import java.math.*;

    class Main{
        public static void main(String[] args){
            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
            NumberFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat();

            double d = input.nextDouble();
            formatter = new DecimalFormat("#.######E0");
            String x = formatter.format(d);
            System.out.println(x.replace("E","*10^");

        }
    }
```

This will print the scientific notation in the decimal format of #.######E0

For example:

If 200 was inputted, the system would return 2 * 10^2.

Comment: I know 2E2 is 2 * 10 ^ 2. But the output should not be 2E2. The output should say `2 * 10 ^ 2 ` specifically.

Comment: You can get it by `result.replace("E", " * 10 ^ ")`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a method which (hopefully) converts all kinds of doubles to their `[-]Factor * 10 ^ [-]Exponent` notation. It's explained inside the code.

edit: There is a [very elegant solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31107558/3004221) by [UnknownOctopus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5056380/unknownoctopus). Still I will leave this here as it does not use any formatters or such, just doubles and Strings - I understood the question wrongly and assumed that only such primitives were allowed.

```
public class Main{
    /**
     * Converts a double to a base10 notation String.
     * 
     * Each String is formatted like this:
     *
     * [-]Factor * 10 ^ [-]Exponent
     *
     * where both, Factor and Exponent, are integer values.
     *
     * @param number the number to convert
     * @return a base10 notation String.
     */
    public static String toScientificNotation(double number) {
        String s = String.valueOf(number);

        int indexPZero = s.indexOf(".0"); // mostly to check if .0 is the end
        int exponent = 0; // simplest case: *10^0

        // Check if the String ends with exactly .0
        if (indexPZero == s.length() - 2) {
            // If the string also has 0s in front of the period, shift those to the 
            // right
            while(s.contains("0.")) {
                number /= 10;
                exponent += 1;
                s = String.valueOf(number);
            }
            // if the string ends in .0 and has no zeros in front of the period we 
            // can format it:
            return String.valueOf(number) + " * 10 ^ " + exponent;
        }

        // If the String does not end in .0, we need to shift to the left.
        // Additionall
        while (indexPZero != s.length() -2) {
            // in case we suddenly reach the scientific notation just substitute it
            s = s.toLowerCase();
            if (s.contains("e")) {
                return s.substring(0, 
                    s.indexOf("e")) + " * 10 ^ " + s.substring(s.indexOf("e")+1);
            }
            // otherwise shift left and reduce the exponent
            number *= 10;
            exponent -= 1;
            s = String.valueOf(number);
            indexPZero = s.indexOf(".0");
        }
        // If we end up here, just write out the number and the exponent.
        return String.valueOf(number) + " * 10 ^ " + exponent;
    }

    public static void main(String... args) {
        double[] vals = { 1, 0.2, 23.4, -32.00004, 0.0002, 10.0 };
        for(double val : vals) {
            System.out.println(val + " becomes " + toScientificNotation(val));
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
1.0 becomes 1.0 * 10 ^ 0
0.2 becomes 2.0 * 10 ^ -1
23.4 becomes 234.0 * 10 ^ -1
-32.00004 becomes -3200004.0 * 10 ^ -5
2.0E-4 becomes 2.0 * 10 ^ -4
10.0 becomes 1.0 * 10 ^ 1
```